# Not sure I am using inheritance/polymorphism issue?

Tags: java

So for this assignment I have to create a car class(parent) and a certifiedpreowned (child) and I need to have the parent class have a method to check if it is still under warranty. *checkWarrantyStatus(). that method calls the boolean isCoveredUnderWarranty() to veryify if the car still has warranty. My issue is in the certifiedpreowned class I have to call the isCoveredUnderWarranty() as well to see if it is covered under the extended warranty and then have it be called via the checkWarrantyStatus() in the car method. I hope this makes sense. So to sum it up I need to in the child class have it check the isCoveredUnderWarranty with extended warranty info. Then it has to move to the parent class so it can be called via checkWarrantyStatus. Here is my code, I have 1 error.

```
    public class Car {

    public int year;
    public String make;
    public String model;
    public int currentMiles;
    public int warrantyMiles;
    public int warrantyYears;
    int currentYear =java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);

    /** construct car object with specific parameters*/
    public Car (int y, String m, String mod, int mi){
    this.year = y;
    this.make = m;
    this.model = mod;
    this.currentMiles = mi;
    }       


    public int getWarrantyMiles() {
    return warrantyMiles;
    }
    public void setWarrantyMiles(int warrantyMiles) {
    this.warrantyMiles = warrantyMiles;
    }
    public int getWarrantyYears() {
    return warrantyYears;
    }
    public void setWarrantyYears(int warrantyYears) {
    this.warrantyYears = warrantyYears;
    }

    public boolean isCoveredUnderWarranty(){
    if (currentMiles < warrantyMiles){
        if (currentYear < (year+ warrantyYears))
    return true;
    }
    return false;       
    }

    public void checkWarrantyStatus(){
    if (isCoveredUnderWarranty()){
    System.out.println("Your car " + year+ " " + make+ " "+ model+ " With "+        

    currentMiles +" is still covered under warranty");
    }
    else
    System.out.println("Your car " + year+ " " + make+ " "+ model+ " With "+ 

    currentMiles +" is out of warranty");

    }
        }

public class CertifiedPreOwnCar extends Car{



public CertifiedPreOwnCar(int y, String m, String mod, int mi) {
    super(mi, m, mod, y);


}
public int extendedWarrantyYears;
public int extendedWarrantyMiles;



public int getExtendedWarrantyYears() {
    return extendedWarrantyYears;
}
public void setExtendedWarrantyYears(int extendedWarrantyYears) {
    this.extendedWarrantyYears = extendedWarrantyYears;
}
public int getExtendedWarrantyMiles() {
    return extendedWarrantyMiles;
}
public void setExtendedWarrantyMiles(int extendedWarrantyMiles) {
    this.extendedWarrantyMiles = extendedWarrantyMiles;
}

public boolean isCoveredUnderWarranty() {
    if (currentMiles < extendedWarrantyMiles){
        if (currentYear < (year+ extendedWarrantyYears))
    return true;
    }
    return false;   
}
}
public class TestCar {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car1 = new Car(2014, "Honda", "Civic", 255);
        car1.setWarrantyMiles(60000);
        car1.setWarrantyYears(5);
        car1.checkWarrantyStatus();

        Car car2 = new Car(2000, "Ferrari", "F355", 8500);
        car2.setWarrantyMiles(20000);
        car2.setWarrantyYears(7);
        car2.checkWarrantyStatus();

        CertifiedPreOwnCar car3 = new CertifiedPreOwnCar(2000, "Honda", "Accord", 65000);   
        car3.setWarrantyYears(3);
        car3.setWarrantyMiles(30000);
        car3.setExtendedWarrantyMiles(100000);
        car3.setExtendedWarrantyYears(7);
        car3.checkWarrantyStatus();





    }           
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing with us the details of your error?

Comment: the error is in the preowned class in the isCoveredUnderWarranty(), currentMiles and year cannot be seen from the Car class. And it says that that instance of isCoveredUnderWarranty, will override the Car.isCoveredUnderWarranty(). So once i fix the error, i am not sure if when i call checkWarrantyStatus() if it will pull from the right spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the base class Car, you set the data members as 'private'.  Children cannot access private members of their super class.  Consider using 'protected' or 'public' for your data members or provide getter (also protected or public) methods for those values in the Car class.

Consider the following example:

```
class Parent {
  private int x;
  protected int y;
  public int z;
}

class Child extends Parent {
  public void doit(){ System.out.println(x); //compiler error }
  public void doit2(){ System.out.println(y); //allowed }
  public void doit3(){ System.out.println(z); //allowed }
}
```

Edit:

For your other problem as stated in the comments on this post, the constructor of CertifiedPreownCar is currently

```
public CertifiedPreOwnCar(int y, String m, String mod, int mi) {
  super(mi, m, mod, y);
}
```

and I believe it should be

```
public CertifiedPreOwnCar(int y, String m, String mod, int mi) {
  super(y, m, mod, mi);
}
```

This is an easy mistake to make with your current variable names.  While it is tempting to choose short variable names, it can introduce simple mistakes and can make your code harder to debug (especially for someone who didn't write it).

Consider using more expressive names such as 'year', 'make', 'model', and 'miles'

Comment: Ok, I did that and the error went away. No I am faced with the other issue. It seems the when I run checkWarrantyStatus() on a car that checks its info in the certifiedpreowned class, it will not check correctly with the parent. EX if i change the years and miles on the warranty and extended warranty to less then the year and miles it will tell me it still has warranty left.

Comment: I made change, in code in post, but as said now the final object car3 in the test class doesnt function right. I know it has to do with it not passing the isCoveredUnderWarranty() to the checkWarrantyStatus in the parent class.

Comment: Are you intending for the output to state that car3 is not under warranty?

Comment: it depend on the variables I put in. Currently it should say it is due to the extended warranty. But if I change the cars mileaget so it would be 50,000 and the extendedWarrantyYears(5) years, it will still say it is covered and it should not be. On the flip side if i made the car a year 2010 and made the setWarranty(5) and extendedsWarrantyYears(0) it should show it is covered and it does not.

Comment: it just seems like it is not passing up from child to parent correctly. And I seem to not see why.

Comment: Yes that sure fixed it. I will be sure to change the names to make them easier to understand. I let eclipse import that info thats why it was out of order. Now on a side note if i make all the extendedWarranty(0) and extenedWarrantyYears(0), and make the setWarranty(10) it should show it is covered but it still does not. Is that because it is only using the isCoveredUnderWarranty() from the child class and not the child then the parent version?

Comment: that is correct since your child function for isCoveredUnderWarranty() only examines extended warranty.  You might consider adding some logic that checks the base warranty and the extended warranty to satisfy the constraint

Comment: Thanks so much, i knew it was something simple as to why none of it pass up thru the classes.